# Basic Ruby - Writing Hashes

Tags: ruby, hash

so writing hashes are straightforward, and it goes a little something like this...

```
  hash = { 'x'=>1, 'y'=>2, 'z'=>3 }
```

but there is another way to do so...

```
  hash_new[:x,1,:y,2,:z,3]
```

So my question is how are the ":x, :y, :z" elements recognized? Are they strings? And under what circumstances is the second method preferred?

Answer (score 1):

Your second example doesn't actually work. The correct syntax is:

```
Hash[:x,1,:y,2,:z,3]
```

The two examples are also actually different. The first has *strings* as keys; the second uses *symbols*.

For more information on what symbols are, see "[Ruby Symbols](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_symbols.html)", "[The Ruby_Newbie Guide to Symbols](http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/ruby/symbols.htm)", "[The Difference Between Ruby Symbols and Strings](http://www.reactive.io/tips/2009/01/11/the-difference-between-ruby-symbols-and-strings/)" or [Ruby's documentation on the `Symbol` class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Symbol.html). (For even *more* information, simply do a Google search for "ruby symbol")

Comment: When creating anchor text, use something more descriptive that helps the reader identify where the link will take them. See "[6.1 Link text](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG10-HTML-TECHS/#link-text)" in "HTML Techniques for Web Content Accessibility Guidelines 1.0" for more information.